# Trazer registros da data de hoje até 1 mês atrás SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço para obter os registros da data de hoje até 1 mês atrás no SQLSERVER?

Sei que por exemplo, com 7 dias, uso GETDATE()-7. Mas e para 1 mês, como ficaria?

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna que contém a data: date? datetime? datetime2? ...

Comment: Tentou `DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `DATEADD`, essa consulta ira retornar a data no ultimo mês começando a partir da ultima meia noite

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, DAY(GETDATE())-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Como faço para obter os registros da data de hoje até 1 mês atrás no SQLSERVER?*

Sugiro que utilize a função [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql).

```
-- código #1
declare @UmMêsAtrás date;
set @UmMêsAtrás= datediff (month, -1, cast (current_timestamp as date));

--
SELECT ...
  from ...
  where coluna_data >= @UmMêsAtrás;
```

É preciso ficar atento a evitar a conversão implícita na cláusula WHERE; assim, a variável @UmMêsAtrás deve ser declarada no mesmo tipo de dados de `coluna_data`. Detalhes no artigo [Os perigos da conversão implícita](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/)